# JS: On page load in stead of onClick

Tags: javascript

i use a button to change the color of a div.
It has this script on it:

```
onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('blue'); return false;"
```

But i want this script to load when the page is loaded. How can i do that?
Tryed this:

```
<body onload="setActiveStyleSheet('blue')">
```

But that did not work.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please don't use inline event handlers, it's bad practice. Use `addEventListener` for cleaner event handling

Comment: Your problem with the inline handler not work probably has to do with the script containing the function not being loaded first.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `addEventListener` to wait for your DOM content load.

```js
function setActiveStyleSheet(color){
  // Function body
  document.getElementById('textContainer').innerHTML = color;
}

// Vanilla JS
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log("DOM is fully loaded and ready for DOM manipulation.");
    setActiveStyleSheet('blue');
});
```

```html
<p id="textContainer"></p>
```

Comment: It should be `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){setActiveStyleSheet('blue')});`

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```
setActiveStyleSheet = function (whichColor){
 $("#myDiv").css('background',whichColor);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setActiveStyleSheet('blue');
});
```

where "myDiv" is the div name.
check in https://jsfiddle.net/2e1nqtq3/16/

Answer (score 0):

Use a script tag at the bottom of the page

```
<body>
...
<script>
  setActiveStyleSheet('blue')
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where DOM manipulation is being executed, this is a very bad idea.  Use event `DOMContentLoaded` instead

Comment: Best to place the script tag inside of body as outside of it is not valid html

Comment: @PatrickAkkers as the others said, this is a dirty hack. You're better off using proper event handlers in a separate script file

Comment: @PatrickAkkers don't use this approach.  There are other answers with a better approach.